# Rails: Model.find() or Model.find_by_id() to avoid RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I just realized I had a very hard to find bug on my website. I frequently use Model.find to retrieve data from my database.

A year ago I merged three websites causing a lot of redirections that needed to be handled. To do I created a "catch all"-functionality in my application controller as this:

```
  around_filter :catch_not_found

  def catch_not_found
    yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      require 'functions/redirections'
      handle_redirection(request.path)
  end
```

in addition I have this at the bottom of my `routes.rb`:

```
  match '*not_found_path', :to => 'redirections#not_found_catcher', via: :get, as: :redirect_catcher, :constraints => lambda{|req| req.path !~ /\.(png|gif|jpg|txt|js|css)$/ }
```

Redirection-controller has:

```
  def not_found_catcher
    handle_redirection(request.path)   
  end
```

I am not sure these things are relevant in this question but I guess it is better to tell.

**My actual problem**

I frequently use Model.find to retrieve data from my database. Let's say I have a Product-model with a controller like this:

```
def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@product.country = Country.find(...some id that does not exist...)
end

# View
<%= @product.country.name %>
```

This is something I use in some 700+ places in my application. What I realized today was that even though the Product model will be found. Calling the Country.find() and NOT find something causes a RecordNotFound, which in turn causes a 404 error.

I have made my app around the expectation that `@product.country = nil` if it couldn't find that Country in the .find-search. I know now that is not the case - it will create a RecordNotFound. Basically, if I load the Product#show I will get a 404-page where I would expect to get a 500-error (since `@product.country = nil` and `nil.name` should not work).

**My question**

My big question now. Am I doing things wrong in my app, should I always use Model.find_by_id for queries like my `Country.find(...some id...)`? What is the best practise here?

Or, does the problem lie within my catch all in the Application Controller?

Comment: FWIW don't rely on dynamic finders being there. A lot of them are deprecated in Rails > 4.0 in favor of "find_by(key: value)" [source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

**should I always use Model.find_by_id**

If you want to find by an id, use `Country.find(...some id...)`. If you want to find be something else, use eg. `Country.find_by(name: 'Australia')`. The `find_by_name` syntax is no longer favoured in Rails 4.

But that's an aside, and is not your problem.

**Or, does the problem lie within my catch all in the Application Controller?**

Yeah, that sounds like a recipe for pain to me. I'm not sure what specifically you're doing or what the nature of your redirections is, but based on the vague sense I get of what you're trying to do, here's how I'd approach it:

Your Rails app shouldn't be responsible for redirecting routes from your previous websites / applications. That should be the responsibility of your webserver (eg nginx or apache or whatever).

Essentially you want to make a big fat list of all the URLs you want to redirect FROM, and where you want to redirect them TO, and then format them in the way your webserver expects, and configure your webserver to do the redirects for you. Search for eg "301 redirect nginx" or "301 redirect apache" to find out info on how to set that up.

If you've got a lot of URLs to redirect, you'll likely want to generate the list with code (most of the logic should already be there in your `handle_redirection(request.path)` method).

Once you've run that code and generated the list, you can throw that code away, your webserver will be handling the redirects form the old sites, and your rails app can happily go on with no knowledge of the previous sites / URLs, and no dangerous catch-all logic in your application controller.

Comment: Let me try to answer a few things at a time here, starting with the least important one. I have reasons to put the redirection in the code since there were no match-up I could do with the past url:s. Basically, I needed a redirection handler. Although I have 301 I still (1 year later) get hits on the old url:s from Google. I have no idea why (issue for another SO-question).

Comment: Let me experiment a bit more with the redirection catcher I have in Application Controller and see where that leads.

Comment: Ok, so basically - if I remove the ApplicationController "catch all" my 404's get all messed up (using the public folder-version and not the one with the layout). I found some middle ground to add this catch all only in the private function "set_product" - this will work they way it was intended. Not an elegant solution perhaps but it will have to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is a very *interesting* way to handle exceptions...

In Rails you use [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) to handle exceptions on the controller layer:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from SomeError, with: :oh_noes

  private def oh_noes
    render text: 'Oh no.'
  end
end
```

However Rails already handles some exceptions by serving static html pages (among them `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`). Which you can [override with dynamic handlers](https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages).

However as @joshua.paling already pointed out you should be handling the redirects on the server level instead of in your application.

Comment: Frankly, this is a solution I got from googling. I had some real issues getting the redirection to work and also the 404 layout to go into the app. This was something that "worked". Obviously not the best way to handle it though.